# How to do a page redirect page in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying to redirect my page to different page in my app.

The problem is that all the url settings are all in my app.js with `ui-route` and I need the redirect happens inside my controller.

so app.js.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {    
    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
            url: '/first',
            templateUrl: 'first.html'
        })
        .state('second', {
            url: '/second',
            templateUrl: 'second.html'
        })
})
```

my controller file

```
app.controller.('firstCtrl' , function(){

    $scope.clickThis=function() {
        //need to redirect to second page...
    }

})
```

How do I redirect to different page inside my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.controller.('firstCtrl' ,["$scope", "$state", function($scope, $state){

    $scope.clickThis=function() {
        $state.go("second");
    }

}]);
```